# How do you set Jenkins stage or pipeline parallel branch status (unstable, failure etc) for use in Stage view and Blue Ocean UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

## Overview

I'm currently configuring a pipeline consisting of a number of platform builds. At the beginning of the pipeline, a user can select which platforms to build or skip.

Depending on whether the 'build' stage for each platform passes or fails, steps in downstream stages can check the status of that platform build and determine whether or not to run. This allows the pipeline to try and complete the other platforms (if confirmed by user to do so) if one or more platforms fail.

## Progress

As it stands, my pipeline achieves this, allowing a user to include/exclude platforms at the start of the pipeline and authorise the pipeline to continue building if a platform fails (but marking the pipeline as a failure). This allows archiving of build files/ publishing gtests etc which may be done in downstream stages/steps. Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```java
// Specify whether or not to build platform by default
def buildDefinitions = [ 'windows' : true , 'macos' : true , 'ubuntu' : true ]

// Keep track of builds that fail
def failedBuilds = [:]

stage('Build Customisation') {
    try {
        // Wait limited amount of time for user input
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {

            // Update the build definitions based on user input
            buildDefinitions = input(
                message: 'Toggle which builds to run (Abort will use default)',

                // Use custom global function to generate boolean input parameters based on a map
                // Sets default value to value in input map
                parameters: generateInputBoolParams( buildDefinitions )
            )
        }

    // Continue pipeline if user input not provided within time limit
    } catch ( error ) {
        echo 'Using default pipeline configuration...'
    }

    // Check that at least one build platform is selected
    if ( !mapContainsTrue( buildDefinitions ) ) {
        error 'No builds selected, aborting pipeline'
    }
}

stage('Conditional Build') {
    parallel (
        'Windows' : {
            // Prevent a build failure from terminating the pipeline after this stage
            try {
                // Check if windows build is set to run
                if ( buildDefinitions['windows'] ) {

                    node('windows') {
                        checkout(scm)
                        bat 'build.bat default-windows'
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Build was disabled by user'
                }

            // Catch an error in the build
            } catch ( error ) {
                // Make note that the build failed
                failedBuilds['windows'] = true

                // Set the pipeline status as failure
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
        },

        'MacOS' : {
            try {
                if ( buildDefinitions['macos'] ) {
                    node('macos') {
                        checkout(scm)
                        sh './build.sh default-macos'
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Build was disabled by user'
                }
            } catch ( error ) {
                failedBuilds['macos'] = true
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
        },

        'Ubuntu' : {
            try {
                if ( buildDefinitions['ubuntu'] ) {
                    node('ubuntu') {
                        checkout(scm)
                        sh './build.sh default-ubuntu'
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Build was disabled by user'
                }
                error 'test error'
            } catch ( error ) {
                failedBuilds['ubuntu'] = true
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
        }
    )

    // Check if any builds have been marked as failed
    if ( mapContainsTrue( failedBuilds ) ) {

        // Remove failed builds from the original map of enabled builds
        def updatedBuildDefinitions = subtractMap( buildDefinitions, failedBuilds )

        // Check that there are builds left to run
        if ( mapContainsTrue( updatedBuildDefinitions ) ) {

            // Update the original build map
            buildDefinitions = updatedBuildDefinitions

            // Lists the failed builds and asks whether to continue or abort the pipeline
            timeout(time: 30, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                input(
                    message: 'Builds failed ' + getKeyset( failedBuilds ) + ', do you want to continue the pipeline and skip failed builds?'
                )
            }
        } else {
            // Throw an error to terminate the pipeline if no builds are left to run
            error 'No builds left to run'
        }
    }
}

stage('Conditional Downstream') {
    parallel (
        'Windows' : {
            if ( buildDefinitions['windows'] ) {
                echo 'You chose to run the windows build!'
            } else {
                echo 'The windows build was skipped'
            }
        },

        'MacOS' : {
            if ( buildDefinitions['macos'] ) {
                echo 'You chose to run the macos build!'
            } else {
                echo 'The macos build was skipped'
            }
        },

        'Ubuntu' : {
            if ( buildDefinitions['ubuntu'] ) {
                echo 'You chose to run the ubuntu build!'
            } else {
                echo 'The ubuntu build was skipped'
            }
        }
    )
}
```

And my global functions:

```java
// subtractMap.groovy
def call ( map1, map2 ) {
    return map1 - map2
}

// mapContainsTrue.groovy
boolean call ( array ) {
    for ( entry in array ) {
        if ( entry.value == true ) {
            isBuildConfigValid = true
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

// getKeyset.groovy
def call ( map ) {
    return map.keySet() as String[]
}

// generateInputBoolParams.groovy
def call ( array ) {
    def parameterList = []
    for ( item in array ) {
        parameterList.add( booleanParam(defaultValue: item.value, name: item.key) )
    }
    return parameterList
}
```

## Problem

While the general functionality works, the UI response does not, aside from marking the pipeline as a failure. I would like to be able to mark the parallel branch as a failure so that in Blue Ocean UI, it is easy to see which platform failed to build.

[Blue Ocean UI with failed parallel branch in try/catch block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km8bF.jpg)

It would also be useful to mark the stage as failed so when not in Blue Ocean UI, the Stage View shows which one failed (unless this only happens if the pipeline is terminated in that stage) although once Blue Ocean is out of Beta this wouldn't really be a problem anymore.

[Stage View failed stage (Above) and as is (Below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkxzX.jpg)

## Question

- How can I mark the parallel branch as failed so that it shows up in Blue Ocean UI with a red cross? Perhaps with an environment variable like `currentBuild.result`
- Is a similar thing possible with the whole stage so that it shows up in Stage View? (Less important)

Comment: Have you find the solution ? I have the similar usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UI response can be achieved by wrapping both the parallel step and the stage step in a try block, throwing the error from the try/catch block within the parallel branch up to the stage block. Not as clean as setting a property but does have the correct UI response for both Blue Ocean and Stage View.

```java
try {
    stage('example') {
        try {
            parallel (
                'A' : {
                    try {
                        // Example...
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        // Mark branch as failed somewhere
                        throw error
                    }
                },
                'B' : {
                    try {
                        // Example...
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        // Mark branch as failed somewhere
                        throw error
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw (error)
        }
        finally {
            // Parallel branch A failed, do you want to continue? etc...
        }
    }
}
catch (error) {
    println (error)
}
```

Comment: While throw will cause `FAILED` - whats the propper way to indicate `UNSTABLE` ?

Comment: according to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39203?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&showAll=true there currently is none :-(

Comment: I am getting proper UI response in Stage view but not in ocean blue.I have used above approach.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Blue Ocean :

```
stage("Global Stage") {
  def parallelStages = [failfast: false]
  parallelStages["Branch 1"] = {
     //Code for branch 1
  }
  parallelStages["Branch 2"] = {
     //Code for branch 2
  }
  catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Branch Failed', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE')
  { parallel parallelStages }
}
```

This properly marks the failed parallel branches as UNSTABLE in Blue Ocean, does not touch other stage results and marks the overall build as SUCCESS